# is_page not triggering

Tags: hooks, conditional-tags

Here is my code:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'ep_tags_redirect_lockout');
function ep_tags_redirect_lockout() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }
    //echo 'XXXXXX';
    if (
        is_page( array(
            16239,
            'new-tag',
            'edit-profile'
        ) )
    ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url( '/' ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

I can tell it gets to the echo statement (when not remarked) but never produces a positive condition with the is_page() function.  I've tried post IDs, slugs, and page names.

Since this is running with the hook 'template_redirect' it should be safe to assume that the page ID is loaded by this time.

Comment: Are you sure your not logged in?  :)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, tested on my install and it works.

Comment: this code will never get to the redirect if you're logged in... is that what you wanted.

Comment: It is supposed to redirect if NOT logged in.  That's where I'm having trouble.  I'm sure I'm not logged in, and to prove it to myself (among other things) if I uncomment the echo statement, I do see THAT.

Comment: Are `new-tag` and `edit-profile` actually _pages_? If `new-tag` is a tag, then you need to use `is_tag()`.

Comment: Yes they are pages.  The "tag" being referred to, is not the same kind of tag you are thinking of.  Those are slugs of actual "pages".  The other is the post_id of a page.

Comment: You might have another plugin also hooking into template_redirect, so add a high priority to it, eg: `add_action('template_redirect', 'ep_tags_redirect_lockout',999);`

Comment: The hook is happening just fine...  It just never satisfies the is_page() conditional.

Comment: I just decided to save myself the trouble, and use `if $post->post_name` instead.